# How to remove an item from Custom listview in fragments in android

Tags: android, listview

I have been facing problem of removing an item from my listview which uses custom adapter in fragments please suggest something

```
       listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

       CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
       listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        return v;
}


class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return phno.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

       view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, 
                                                                  null);
       Button btn =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    listview.removeViewAt(i);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

     return view;
}
```

The app shut down n clicking the cancel_button

Comment: Post error log please

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeViewAt(int) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.removeViewAt(AdapterView.java:535)

Comment: Try this `listview.remove(i)`

Comment: this method is not supported

Comment: Well, I assume that you are supplying a list to the adapter, why don't you remove the item from the list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?